# How to correctly use functions in a class?

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I'm having a difficulty implementing functions in the class ArrayQ. The task is to create a class and have three methods in it, enqueue, dequeue and isEmpty. In "self.array.append(self.array)" I'm not really sure if it's supposed to be array,self.array,self or something else in the parenthesis. The basictest() function below was given to us to controll that our class works, and it doesn't at the moment.

```
from array import array
    
class ArrayQ:
    def __init__(self,array):
        self.array = array

    def enqueue(self):
        self.array.append(self.array)

    def dequeue(self):
        self.array.pop(0)

    def isEmpty(self):
        if not self.array:
            print("queue is empty")

#print(ArrayQ)
lista = []

def basictest():
    q = ArrayQ(lista)
    q.enqueue(1)
    q.enqueue(2)
    x = q.dequeue()
    y = q.dequeue()
    if (x == 1 and y == 2):
        print("test OK")
    else:
        print("FAILED expexted x=1 and y=2 but got x =", x, " y =", y)
    
basictest()
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d1.py", line 31, in <module>
    basictest()
  File "d1.py", line 22, in basictest
    q.enqueue(1)
TypeError: enqueue() takes 1 positional 
argument but 2 were given
```

So could anybody please guide me towards how I should solve this problem so I could make this code work? Among the presumably several errors in this code, why can't I use "q.enqueue(1)" to alter my list using the function, or method, written in the class?

Comment: The first problem is that the code isn't indented correctly.

Comment: Please go through this tutorial series to understand the concept of classes.  Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM

Comment: @mkrieger1, it is intended correctly, this is my first stackoverflow question, so I apparently didn't paste the code here correctly, but it is accurate in my program.

Comment: @TanishqVyas, thank you! I've heard of Corey Schafer's tutorials. I'll make sure to watch them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here.

```
def enqueue(self):
    self.array.append(self.array)
```

This method takes one param: `self`. It's a reference of that object, so, unless you've got a `classmethod` your class methods *must* have a `self` param as first parameter.

Now, your `basictest()` function calls a `q.enqueue(1)` but your object q is a `ArrayQ` and its `enqueue` function has only one parameter: `self`. It's implicitly, you cannot use `1` as `self`.
So, edit `enqueue` in this way:

```py
def enqueue(self, value):
    self.array.append(value)
```

Comment: thank you truly, now I see where the problem is!

Comment: I now have the following problem: my basictest() doesn't work as you can see in: https://imgur.com/BIGLngp. I kind of get it to work now, but the basic test messes up a bit. Isn't it necessary to enter an argument in parentheses in "q = ArrayQ ()", I mean you have to give it a list to process, right? I also wonder how the test function is structured. I do not get "test OK". Isn't it supposed that the list is filled with "1" and "2" and then the it is emptied. So why should "x = q.dequeue ()" have the value 1?

Comment: You've got this problem 'cause `dequeue()` returns None, so both x and y are None. You have to edit the `dequeue()` function with `return self.array.pop(0)` as body.

Comment: oh ok, I see! Now x and y do have values. Do I also need to edit `enqueue()` and/or `isEmpty()` to include `return`?

Comment: Well, if you want to manage a return valuable yes. You could edit `enqueue()` adding `return value` and `isEmpty()` with `return len(self.array) == 0`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is an incorrect indentation in the class "ArrayQ". And second, there is only one default argument is passed in the **"enqueue"** method definition. When you create an instance of an object, the object itself is passed as a default argument(self). In **"q.enqueue(1)"** you are actually passing two parameters, first is **self** and the second is **"1"**.

Comment: thank you for enlightening me on the concept of instance creation of an object! Regarding the indentations, I'm afraid that it is intended correctly. This is my first stackoverflow question, so I apparently didn't paste the code here correctly, but it is accurate in my program.

Comment: I now have the following problem: my basictest() doesn't work as you can see in: imgur.com/BIGLngp. I kind of get it to work now, but the basic test messes up a bit. Isn't it necessary to enter an argument in parentheses in "q = ArrayQ ()", I mean you have to give it a list to process, right? I also wonder how the test function is structured. I do not get "test OK". Isn't it supposed that the list is filled with "1" and "2" and then the it is emptied. So why should "x = q.dequeue ()" have the value 1?